# How to use new feature of spring boot 3.1 docker-compose in spring boot tests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I tried add docker-compose.yml in test resourse, but container didn't deploy, can you give some instructions to connect my test with spring-boot-docker-compose

I want connect my tests with spring-boot-docker-compose. All plugins has been wrote in build.gradle

Comment: Solved: In application.yaml in test/resources package should add spring.docker.compose.skip.intests: false

Comment: Docker Compose support is disabled in tests in favor of using Testcontainers in tests. Why testcontainers lifecycle aligns better with tests then global docker compose support.